# Combobox selected value are null while scrolling listview in UWP

Tags: c#

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,5" Padding="0,0,5,0"  DataFetchSize="10" IncrementalLoadingThreshold="5" IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding InfiniteCUItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Style="{StaticResource NormalListView}"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NormalListViewItem}"
                          >
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    
                    <cucontrol:Simplified CUName="{Binding CUName}"
                                                                 ItemDescription="{Binding ItemDescription}"
                                                                 KeyName="{Binding KeyName}"
                                                                 StationName="{Binding StationName}"
                                                                 WorkFunction="{Binding SelectedWorkFunction}"
                                                                 IsActualQuantityEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, ElementName=Simplified}"
                                                                 
                                                                 CompleteCUStatusConfirmCommand="{Binding DataContext.CompleteCUStatusConfirmCommand, ElementName=Simplified}"
                                                                 MaterialCollection="{Binding Materials}"
                                                                 CUCollection="{Binding CUCollection}">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateCUCommand, ElementName=Simplified}"
                                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="LostFocus">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ValidateCUQtyCommand, ElementName=SimplifiedCUAsBuiltPage}"
                                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </cucontrol:SimplifiedCUControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
            </ListView>
```

We have IincrementalLoadCollection for collection type. When we scroll listview, the selectedvalue for combobox and text for textboxcontrol gets blanked.

We did some research and found that we need to disable the virtulization for listview. so, We did that too by

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                    
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

but after placing above code, when we scroll listview, the selectedvalue issue gets resolved but we are getting below error
**AccessViolationException was unhandled Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt**

Any suggestion/help please.